# Importing sympy and matplotlib.pyplot causes a deprecation warning

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, sympy

This runs fine without any warnings or errors,

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
```

This,

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import sympy
plt.plot(range(10))
```

Produces,

```py
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:327: 
DeprecationWarning: Gtk.Window.set_wmclass is deprecated
  self.window.set_wmclass("matplotlib", "Matplotlib")
```

Note that if you import them both but don't call the plot function, you don't get the deprecation warning.

I have no idea what is going on. Googling that warning does not quite find anything related to Sympy. Python is at `3.8.5`, Sympy at `1.8` and Matplotlib at `3.4.0`.

Comment: I ran your code with python 3.9 and Sympy 1.8, there was no warning. So probably you can try updating python .

Comment: I installed Python with `apt install` and will rather let it keep maintaining it. Could you test it with 3.8.5?

Comment: unfortunately i don't have a 3.8.5 installed. By the way, if this warning is bugging you, you can just disable it. Otherwise, this DeprecationWarning seems harmless .

Answer (score 0):

The message you received is a `warning` and not an `error`. The difference being that your code has been executed normally, the message provides *extra* information that in some point in the future `Gtk.Window.set_wmclass` will not be available, it's a note to programmers (in this case the `matplotlib` devs) that they should change their code to use the *new* way of doing something. If you use a combination of old/new packages you should expect to see these warnings.

You can either ignore/suppress this warning message, or update your packages.

It's recommended that you use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to isolate the Python that you use to from the Python that your system uses. It will allow you to use up-to-date versions of packages and you will no longer risk accidentally breaking system utilities. There are many options and since Python ~3.6 there's the `venv` module included in the standard library.

Comment: @JohnHennig If you look at sympy's init method it sets it makes calls to matplotlib (via init method of it's plot class). The packages are not unrelated, see the sympy docs. To reproduce OPs error you'd (probably) need a specific combinations of out-of-date packages on a system and running in a GUI environment so that the 'default' backend would be inferred to Gtk. None of this would be useful for OP, the solution would be to upgrade or ignore/suppress the warning. My answer explains how OP can go about upgrading without affecting their system Python which they mentioned in their comment.

Comment: @JohnHennig "And why would the import of a seemingly unrelated package trigger that warning? " That's your interpretation, OP didn't ask a specific question. They said they "have no idea what's going on".  You're free to suggest a better or more useful answer of your own.

Comment: I think @JohnHennig does have a better understanding of my question. I know it is recommended that I use virtual environments but really, I don't see a point in doing so until someone has to replicate my environment. Also, my python is not that old. It is the standard package that comes with Ubuntu Mate using `apt` so it is not like I am on some archaic system.

Comment: @scribe Can you try to explain what you question is? This Q and A section is for clearly defined problems. If you'd like to understand what happens you feel step by step and ask questions feel free to message me in chat. If you want to understand yourself look at the files called `init.py`  and  `plotting.py` in sympy they'll connect you to your warning. If you simply don't like seeing the warning import sympy first. I suggested a venv as a means of isolating packages, not multiple versions of python.